# How to know whether the data passed to GPU will cause CUDA out of memory or not

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

I am using GPU to run some very large deep learning models, when I choose a batch size of 8, it can fit into the memory, but if I use a batch size of 16, it will cause CUDA out-of-memory error, and I have to kill the process.

My question is, before actually passing the data into GPU, is there a way that I could know how large the data will occupy in the GPU?

For example, the following code is about how I create a pytorch dataloader and pass each batch of the dataloader to the GPU, could I know how large it is before I call `batch.to(device)`

```
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)
for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
    b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
    b_labels = batch[2].to(device)
```

Comment: The data itself will take tensor.numel() * 4 bytes (4 bytes if your data uses datatype float32 that is). But the feature tensors that are generated in the model are probably going to be much larger than that. In theory you'd have to know how large the output per sample is for each layer in your model, but a more pragmatic approoach might be to a) measure GPU memory usage with batch_size=1 vs batch_size=2 and extrapolate or b) add hooks to all of your model's layers and sum up their output_tensor sizes (for batch_size=1). However, b) only works if your model has no deeper nested child modules.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the torchsummary package here.

```
pip install torchsummary
```

and in use

```
from torchsummary import summary
myModel.cuda()
summary(myModel, (shapeOfInput)) # where shapeOfInput is a tuple of the sample's dimensions
```

This will give you the size of the model, the size of the forward pass, and the size of the backpass in MB for a batch size of 1, and you can then multiple out by your batch size.